# In a class, there are 15 boys and 10 girls. Three students are selected at random. The probability that 1 girl and 2 boys are selected, is:

Tags: probability

> Then, n(S) = Number ways of selecting 3 students out of 25 = 25C3 =
>   2300.
>
> n(E)= (10C1 x 15C2) = 1050
>
> P(E) = n(E)/n(s) = 1050/2300 = 21/46

I know the above method of obtaining answer using formula.

> But without applying the formula, trying to solve it , gives
>   me a different answer.

Probability of selecting girl = 10/25

Next, Probability of selecting 1 boy = 15/24 
(24 because 1 girl is already selected)

Next, Probability of selecting another boy = 14/23 
(23 because 1 boy and 1 girl were already selected)
(14 because 1 boy was already selected before)

So,

> P(E) = n(E)/n(s) = (10x15x14)/(25x24x23)=2100/13800=21/138=**7/46**

why am i getting 7/46 ?

Comment: Your second method is the probability of very specifically picking in sequence a girl followed by a boy followed by another boy.  If you were to pick in sequence though, for the original problem you could also have picked a boy then a girl then a boy or also picked two boys and then a girl, each scenario being just as likely to occur as the one you calculated, making your answer off by a factor of three.

Comment: so, what should i do to get 21/46 ?

Comment: Multiply your answer of $\frac{7}{46}$ by three to account for the three different orders that you could arrange the genders of the people you selected so that the overall outcome totals two boys and one girl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are selecting $2$ of $15$ boys, $1$ of $10$ girls, and $3$ of $25$ total people, the probability is $${{15\choose{2}} {10\choose{1}}}\over{{25\choose{3}}}$$ $$= \frac{21}{46}$$

Your second method is incorrect because you are assuming we select a girl, a boy, and then another boy in that particular order. In reality, it can be any order $gbb$, $bgb$, $bbg$, giving $3$$7\over{46}$ $=$ $21\over46$